# Android & ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Не знаю, как реализовать подобное c помощью ExpandableListView:

[image]

Набор массивов по структуре такой:

```
String[] Day=new String[]{"Название"};
String[] Time=new String[]{"11:45"};
String[] Name=new String[]{"Кука"};
```

Как с двумя массивами сделать - знаю, но как с тремя и чтобы был подобный вывод - не понимаю. (

Comment: благодарю=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте свой адаптер, в конструктор которого передавайте 3 массива. Переопределите у него getChildView  
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20custom%20expandablelistview%20adapter%20example&es_th=1